# Force Company Wide Gmail Theme for Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I know how to enable and disable user theme choice in my domain management admin, but I'm hoping to do a custom theme company wide that is enforced inside Google Apps admin. Is this possible?

I've already put in a custom logo, but I'm hoping to just make a couple tweaks to selection, button and background colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API call to change or force users to use a certain Gmail theme. However, with the [newly announced](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/gmail-shelfies-are-so-yesterday-share.html) "Share your theme" capability, you could share your theme with users and require them to use that theme.

Comment: Good find. I hope that now that sharing is available that they will allow us to define user themes on the Apps admin level.